# Correct piece of script to use to get layer to toggle open on windowload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onload-event

I am looking for the correct piece of the following script to use as a window load function to get the layer to toggle open on load.

This is the code for expanding the layer:

```
$(function() {
Sitemap.init();

});

var Sitemap = { 
Content: null,
Trigger: null,  
init: function() {
    var cc = this;
    cc.Content = $('#Sitemap div.content');
    cc.Trigger = $('#ToggleSiteMap');
    cc.events();
},
events: function() {
    var cc = this;
    cc.Trigger.click(function(){
        cc.Content.slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
}
};
```

Which part should I take to create an `onload` script like the below that will open the layer on load? Have tried all elements and cant seem to get it to work. Would really appreciate the help.

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript"> window.onload=help needed here;
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the init function on loading of the page you can do like dis.
Your question is unclear, elaborate more about the need

```
$(window).load(function(){
Sitemap.init();
});
```

You can use this if you want to get function invoked "not waitingfor the images to be get downloaded"

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
Sitemap.init(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. i need to call the script to open the layer onload .. please see the page here http://www.basedesigns.co.uk/Group7Events/ .. at present it opens on click but i need it to also open onwindowload

Comment: You want that the layer should be expand format from load and after that toggle process should work

Answer (score 0):

Am not getting your question correctly.

If i assume that you need to execute init() of sitemap object then you can simply call init function like this:

```
window.onload = Sitemap.init();
```

or

```
(function() { 
    Sitemap.init();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. I need to use the part of the script that opens the layer to be called on windowload. I am not sure which part of the code this is.. Is it ToggleSitemap ? at the moment it is called from a button <a href="#" id="ToggleSiteMap" title="change window size"><img src="img/toggle_conference.png" width="45" height="35" /></a>

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the site, i figured that If you want to open the layer in full view you have to make changes in following section on HTML page

```
<div id="Sitemap">
<div class="wrp">
<div class="content cF" style="display: none;"></div>    
</div>
```

change it to

```
<div id="Sitemap">
<div class="wrp">
<div class="content cF" style="display: block;"></div>    
</div>
```

It will do, no need to call any function , or make new method